# Nuxt with typescript, vuex error: This dependency was not found: ..\store\index.ts in ./.nuxt/store.js

Tags: nuxt.js

I create empty nuxt project using npm as specified in [nuxt installation page](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/installation). I choose to use the typescript version. Then serve this new project with `npm run dev`. The app is working fine. But then I create a file at `store/index.ts`, and after that, this is the error that I am getting:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                       friendly-errors 19:06:00

This dependency was not found:                                                                friendly-errors 19:06:00
                                                                                              friendly-errors 19:06:00
* ..\store\index.ts in ./.nuxt/store.js
```

Software versions:

```
OS: Windows 11
npm: 8.1.0
node: 16.13.0
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-nuxt-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.ts,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js",
    "lintfix": "npm run lint:js -- --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.3",
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^8.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.3",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the content of your `store/index.ts` file?

Comment: @NicolasPennec just empty file right now. Same error with minimal store setup also.

Comment: Issue got resolved after tinkering with npm and node versions

Answer (score 0):

Didn't figure out what was the problem, but the issue got resolved after some tinkering with npm and node versions. Multiple uninstalling/reinstalling attempts, and then creating new nuxt app did the trick.